# Laravel. Insert array to raw sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array `$blshopids = [5,8];` that I want to insert into a raw SQL statement:

```
$blshopids = [5,8];
$blshops = implode(",", $blshopids);
$product = 1;

...
where p1.product_id = :product
and p1.shop_id not in (:blshops)
..., ['product' => $product, 'blshops' = $blshops];
```

As you guess $blshops becomes a string `'5,8'` and I get `p1.shop_id not in ('5,8')` instead of `p1.shop_id not in (5,8)`. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: please show us the entire php code you are using to build your query.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. How to turn array into comma separated integers? Query doesn't really matter.

Comment: Check whereNotIn on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses). Also check (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)